# FireDac Firebird and Android

Tags: android, delphi, firebird, firedac

Are there any other components I need to establish a firebird connection on a mobile android device in addition to FireDac?  I have set up and tested a connection to a remote server using Firedac, but when I try to run the application on an Android device, it hangs trying to make the connection.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You can't connect directly since you are (probably) missing the client library on the device.

I'm not aware of availability of the client library for Android platform but I saw this http://www.firebirdnews.org/?p=8786 article by Mariuz.

If you want to connect to a database from a mobile app, you should consider to go for a multitier approach (DataSnap or similar).