# How to install a Firebird driver on android so I can connect with FireDac

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle, firedac

In Delphi Seattle 10 have a program that connects with a remote Firebird db (testing program on Windows).

When I port it on a mobile device with android I have an exception due to a missing driver .
The topic is not so young (about 3 years). 
[FireDac Firebird and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107213/firedac-firebird-and-android)
and I found this http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/
that is a java driver (probably work with the new Firebird v 3).
But I really don't know how if it is a good driver for android and, if so, how to install it on a mobile device.

Due the fact that the remote db is a firebird db (server version) and, with my other program I have no problem to connect, read, work on it (win 7/10 + Delphi Seattle 10 + FireDac), is there a way to achieve this connection?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that explains the problem or question you're asking, in a way that will have value to future readers who see it in a search result. You've done nothing but repeat information that is in the question tags, so your title is absolutely lacking in information. Thanks.

Comment: Firebird does not support mobile OSes. Which is the source of your troubles. Interbase (starting from Interbase XE3) does and if you're able to migrate to that your problem should be solved.  Unfortunately that was true in 2012 and is still the case in 2016, see: http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-3-0-0/

Comment: Investigate multi-tier applications. If you do this, you will have a "server" application compiled for Win32/64 connecting to the database and your Android app will connect to the "server"app  using tcp/ip or http. The "server" is then the middle-tier of a 3-tier system. One way to do this is with Embarcadero Datasnap.

Comment: In situations like this, you should really consider re-thinking your system design, and consider building a REST API server, or something of the sort. Mobile devices really are not meant to connect directly to a raw database of any sort. This is rather a security flaw.

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect to Firebird on Android because Firebird does not support Mobile OSes. It only officially supports Windows and Linux.
Using the jdbc driver will not help because that requires Java 7 and android does not run Java 7, it runs it's own flavour called Android.

The closest alternative to Firebird is Interbase. Interbase has support for Android starting with the XE3 release (IIRC).

Comment: what about now?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the database in mobile.

My suggestion is to use `SQLite` or `IBLite` or `MSSQL`. 
And through FireDAC, components connect with the database.

These Mobile and Windows databases and need not drivers.

Database connection method to FireDac, such as ADO connection with the database.

More information: [docwiki.embarcadero.com/Using_FireDAC_and_SQLite](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_FireDAC_and_SQLite_(iOS_and_Android))

Or: [docwiki.embarcadero.com/Using_FireDAC_in_Mobile_Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_FireDAC_in_Mobile_Applications_(iOS_and_Android))

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to connect to a Firebird database from Android but it involves a 3rd party product and creating a server app/service on a windows device.

You can use RemoveDB from TMS Software:- http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/remotedb.asp

It is really simple, takes few minutes to create a server and their client end allows full Firebird queries to be run.